# Adding a 2d histogram to a python cartopy plot causes the extent to be reset

Tags: python, cartopy

I am writing a program that displays a heat map of lightning strikes over a cartopy plot. Using a scatter plot work; however when I try to implement the 2d histogram, the map becomes zoomed out all the way.
[Plot before adding histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Why.png)
[Plot after adding histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzQkP.png)

Here is the code
lon_small and lat_small are the coordinate arrays.

```
proj = ccrs.LambertConformal()
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10),subplot_kw=dict(projection=proj))
#FEATURES
#state_borders = cfeat.NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural', name="admin_1_states_provinces_lakes",             scale = '10m', facecolor = 'none')
extent = ([-99,-92, 27, 31.3])
xynps = ax2.projection.transform_points(ccrs.PlateCarree(), lon_array, lat_array)

ax.set_extent(extent)
ax.set_extent(extent)

ax.add_feature(USCOUNTIES.with_scale('5m'), edgecolor = "gray")
ax.add_feature(state_borders, linestyle='solid', edgecolor='black')
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, dms=True, x_inline=False, y_inline=False)

#Adding scatter plots
ax.scatter(-95.36, 29.76, transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(), marker='*', s = 400, color = "orange")   #Houston 
ax.scatter(lon_small, lat_small, transform = ccrs.PlateCarree(), marker='.', s=0.001, c = "red")
#Adding Histogram
h = ax.hist2d(xynps[:,0], xynps[:,1], bins=100, zorder=10, alpha=0.75, cmin=120)
plt.show()
```

I have checked online for people with a similar problem, but I can't find anything like this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's a note in the docstring of `hist2d` stating:

```
Currently hist2d calculates its own axis limits, and any limits previously set are ignored.
```

... so i guess the easiest way to maintain initial limits is to do something like this:

```
...
extent = ax.get_extent(crs=ax.projection)
ax.hist2d(...)
ax.set_extent(extent, crs=ax.projection)
...
```

Comment: The code you have fixes the zoom-out problem; however, it looks like the 2D histogram is  performing the bin while the plot is still zoomed out. Here is the result with the bin set to 50 https://imgur.com/X5gan1n

Comment: You can be more explicit with your limits, or even use Numpy's 2d histogram with `ax.imshow` or `pcolormesh`. But it's impossible to replicate your issue without the data, or some toy example.